# Circuit to power LEDs with various regulated output voltages on circuit?

Tags: led, voltage-regulator

I'm designing a PCB with a few regulators on it. I will put some status LEDs on the output of each regulator to indicate that it's on. I'm thinking of some combination of 24V, 17V, 12V and 5V.

I'm not sure what circuit to put on the output so that I can safely power the LED without smoking it. Does anyone have any advice on a circuit to handle the higher output voltages and power the LEDs?

Comment: Why can't you just use a resistor?

Answer (score 1):

Choose regulators with ‘power good’ outputs, then drive your LEDs with those signals.